# Reading meta information from RAW

Tags: java, image, metadata

I found some example for reading meta information from a Picture but it fails if i enter a raw file. (NEF)

```
void readAndDisplayMetadata( String fileName ) {
    try {
        File file = new File( fileName );

        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);

        if (readers.hasNext()) { //here fails

            ImageReader reader = readers.next();
            reader.setInput(iis, true);
            IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);

            String[] names = metadata.getMetadataFormatNames();
            int length = names.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                System.out.println( "Format name: " + names[ i ] );
                displayMetadata(metadata.getAsTree(names[i])); //print out as xml
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I create one of the objekts with that method and call it with the file "test.nef" which fails. If i try the test.png it works. i wonder whats wrong with this. I guess that the reader cant handle raw formats. Is there a better way to get the meta information of a picture? (Like aperture, iso and so on)

Answer (score 0):

[ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) supports JPEG,PNG, BMP, WBMP, FIG. To register custom formats use [SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/package-summary.html)